# Java passing of parameter

Tags: java, variables, parameter-passing

Can someone please explain in a little detail to me why this code prints 2?

```
import java.util.*;

public class TestCode2 {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int[][] array = {{1,2,3,4}, {5,6,7,8}};
      System.out.println(m1(array)[0]);
     // System.out.println(m2(array)[1]);
   }

   public static int[] m1(int[][] m) {
      int[] result = new int[2];
      result[0] = m.length;
      result[1] = m[0].length;
      return result;
   }
}
```

Comment: Why are you surprised? Your code is equivalent to printing `array.length`, which is indeed 2.

Comment: I'm assuming you're expecting the result to be 8. However, the length of `array` in `main()` is two. The two elements inside of it just happen to be arrays of length 4.

Answer (score 3):

```
    int[][] array = {{1,2,3,4}, {5,6,7,8}};
=>  int[][] array = {arrayOne, arrayTwo};
```

The length of array is 2 because it's just a bi-dimensionnal array which contains 2 sub arrays (which have both a length of 4).

So

```
   array.length = 2;
   array[0].length = length of arrayOne (i.e: length of {1,2,3,4}) = 4
   array[1].length = length of arrayTwo (i.e: length of {5,6,7,8}) = 4
```

---

To summarize :

```
public static int[] m1(int[][] m) {
      int[] result = new int[2];
      result[0] = m.length; //m.length = 2
      result[1] = m[0].length; //m[0].length = length of {1,2,3,4} = 4
      return result; //{2,4}
   }
```

Then you just print the first element of this array returned, i.e 2.

Comment: Thank you, I actually just mixed up what m.length and m[0].length meant. Dumb mistake. Just learned about arrays and recursion yesterday

Answer (score 1):

This is a 2d array so :
when you do like this :
int [][] array = {{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8}}
int a=array.length; \ i.e a=2
this is because the array treats the 2 sets as its element means {1,2,3,4} and {5,6,7,8} are considered as single element
sorry for wrong format as i am using mobile

Answer (score 1):

m1() is taking 2D array as i/p & returning a (1D) array with first element as length of the i/p array, which - in this case is 2; Hence 2.